# mysqli_fetch_array() not producing an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, resultset

I can't seem to be able to place the resultset into an array and then use print_r to print out the array.  Here's the script:

```
<?php

require( 'wp-load.php' );

$local = 'xxx';
$user  = 'xxx'; 
$pass  = 'xxx';
$data  = 'xxx';

$testConnection  = mysqli_connect($local,$user,$pass, $data); 


if (!$testConnection) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL);
}
echo 'Database connection working!';


global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->options" );


/* this is commented out but works 

foreach ( $result as $row )   {
echo $row->option_id.'<br>';
}   
*/  

//PART NOT WORKING    

$results = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    echo "hello";  //never executes?????
    $results[] = $row;

}

//$results has all that you need
print_r($results);  //empty array??? 




 $testClosed = mysqli_close($testConnection);



 if ($testClosed) {
     echo "closed";
 }


?>
```

Comment: Your `$result` should have been produced by `mysqli_query` instead of `$wpdb->get_results` for `mysqli_fetch_array` to work.

Comment: tried that but it doesn't seem to work. can you show a working example?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->options" ); foreach ( $result as $row )   {
$results[] = $row;
}`?

Comment: @DCR: Can you update the question to the current code that you tried?

Comment: @koala yeung msqli_query did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM))
{
    echo "hello";  //never executes?????
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Try removing the while statement out of there. Array is going to be given to you with `mysqli_fetch_array` . So just write it like this :

```php
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
 $results[] = $row;
```

You could just access the indexes with $row[...] but still, up to you.

On the other hand :

On the documentation for the function there is such statement :
`Return Value: Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row. NULL if there are no more rows in result-set`
. So you might be calling a invalid table from your DB.